# Setting scrolling on a specific portion of the webpage

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

https://plnkr.co/edit/FvCTLHHfQA9KNAlfVYAP?p=preview

```
<clr-main-container>
 <div class="content-container">
  <div class="content-area">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9" style="height:100%; border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); padding-right:0; overflow-y: auto;">
      <div class="container">
        left column
        <clr-tabs (clrTabsCurrentTabLinkChanged)="onTabSelected($event)" (clrTabsCurrentTabIndexChanged)="onTabIndexChanged($event)" (clrTabsCurrentTabContentChanged)="onTabContentActivated($event)">
          <clr-tab-link [clrTabLinkActive]="true">Tab 1</clr-tab-link>
            <clr-tab-content [clrTabContentActive]="true" style="overflow-y: auto;"> 
              SOME VERY LONG CONTENT THAT EXCEEDS 100vh in height;
            </clr-tab-content>
          <clr-tabs>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs">
      right column
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</clr-main-container>
```

I am trying to implement a layout such that the height of my html document is always 100vh, and if the content of a particular tab exceeds that height, then it should scroll instead of overshoot the length. However, in my implementation, the scroll behavior is getting applied to the entire page, instead of just the tab content.

What are some better ways of doing this? I have been able to identify that setting a height value to my content manually correctly sets the scroll behavior, however, I do not think that setting a height manually is the most optimum way of designing this layout. If my content div knew the height of the parent and stretched itself all the way to the bottom, maybe that might solve my problem. I am not too sure though.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS

https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

There are many scroll plugins but You must test it for mobiles.

Comment: thank you for sharing that. Is there a more CSS only solution to this? I feel that introducing JS to do that seems like an overkill at the moment.

Comment: overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; but it's hard to say when I do not have access to page.

Comment: I have added a plunkr in the post, if you need access to the code structure.

Comment: just add height to your content container. Add some class to 'col-xs-9' like 'col-xs-9 my_class' and then in CSS .my_class{max-height:400px;}